# How to make custom theme in Android Picker (Style)

Tags: android, themes, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, android-calendar

I'm facing a situation and I can't find the solution, I've a Alloy app, and I've created a 'input' with it's own options, in iOS it shows a popup with a UI.Picker, and in android shows only the UI.Picker like a dropdown, my problem is that the background is dark and the text white, I've tried to add a theme to tiapp.xml and add some properties to it, but nothing changed yet; I also want to apply this in the alert dialogs, this is my tiapp.xml file:

```
 <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <tool-api-level>14</tool-api-level>
        <manifest>
            <application 
                android:debuggable="true"
                android:largeHeap="true"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme">
                <activity ... ></activity>
            </application>
            <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/>
        </manifest>
    </android>
```

This is my app/platform/android/res/values/style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/text</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/picker</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/picker</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/picker</item>
        <item name="android:color">#555</item>
        <item name="android:background">#FFF</item>
    </style>
    <style name="text" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:color">#555</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#555</item>
        <item name="android:background">#FFF</item>
    </style>
    <style name="picker" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:color">#555</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#555</item>
        <item name="android:background">#FFF</item>
    </style>
    <style name="alert" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#555</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#555</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#555</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#555</item>
        <item name="android:background">#FFF</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

UPDATE:

This is my iOS picker:

[image: iOSPicker]

This is my android picker:

[image]

Comment: el picker lo abris en un modal?

Comment: Can you provide a screen of how you see it on iOS and how you see it on android?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I facing the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Digging through the code at https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/415bd6c66dcc55b1a59a59574f3babd3c3a84ede/android/modules/ui/src/java/ti/modules/titanium/ui/widget/picker/TiUINativePicker.java#L93 this component is styled by https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/415bd6c66dcc55b1a59a59574f3babd3c3a84ede/android/modules/ui/res/layout/titanium_ui_spinner.xml so you'd need to override that id in your custom theme.

Comment: So I only need to paste 'android:id="@+id/titanium_ui_spinner"' in me style.xml ? can you tell me where exactly?

Comment: Reading through http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html and http://blog.danlew.net/2014/11/19/styles-on-android/ I'm not exactly sure. Could you create a JIRA ticket with a request to be able to style these components from a custom theme? We might need to add style-attributes to all widgets in the SDK for that.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll read that. I've created a JIRA ticket: [AC-3590](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-3590)